# Fail to AsyncTask update progressBar's progress when first enter the fragment ListView, then okay after scroll ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

The progressbar cannot show progress if without scroll down and back to same position visit again, detail please check this demo:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGu8MyUHidQ&feature=youtu.be
```

No exception or error, maybe ListView bug or logic error, anyone have any idea?

DownloadInfo class:

```
private final static String TAG = DownloadInfo.class.getSimpleName();
public enum DownloadState {
    NOT_STARTED,
    QUEUED,
    DOWNLOADING,
    COMPLETE
}
private volatile DownloadState mDownloadState = DownloadState.NOT_STARTED;
private final String mFilename;
private volatile Integer mProgress;
private final Integer mFileSize;
private volatile ProgressBar mProgressBar;

public DownloadInfo(String filename, Integer size) {
    mFilename = filename;
    mProgress = 0;
    mFileSize = size;
    mProgressBar = null;
}
//Follow by getters & setters
```

DownloadInfoArrayAdapter Class:

```
public class DownloadInfoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DownloadInfo> {
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button button;
    DownloadInfo info;
}

public DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(Context context, List<DownloadInfo> objects) {
    super(context, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final DownloadInfo info = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (null == row) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_download_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileName);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
        holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
        holder.info = info;
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.info.setProgressBar(null);
        holder.info = info;
        holder.info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);
    }

    holder.textView.setText(info.getFilename());
    holder.progressBar.setProgress(info.getProgress());
    holder.progressBar.setMax(info.getFileSize());
    info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);

    holder.button.setEnabled(info.getDownloadState() == DownloadState.NOT_STARTED);
    final Button button = holder.button;
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            info.setDownloadState(DownloadState.QUEUED);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            button.invalidate();
            FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(info);
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    });
    return row;
}
}
```

FileDownloadTask class:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mInfo.setProgress(values[0]);
    ProgressBar bar = mInfo.getProgressBar();
    if (bar != null) {
        bar.setProgress(mInfo.getProgress());
        bar.invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting download for " + mInfo.getFilename());
    mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
    for (int i = 0; i <= mInfo.getFileSize(); ++i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(i);
    }
    mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
}
```

In the fragment add click listener

```
lvStickerGroup = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.lvStickerGroup);
    List<DownloadInfo> downloadInfo = new ArrayList<DownloadInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        downloadInfo.add(new DownloadInfo("File " + i, 1000));
    }

    adapter = new DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(activity, downloadInfo);
    lvStickerGroup.setAdapter(adapter); 
    lvStickerGroup.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "bla" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //Testing all below, no luck
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvStickerGroup.invalidate();
    lvStickerGroup.invalidateViews();
    lvStickerGroup.refreshDrawableState();

    lvStickerGroup.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int a = 0; a < lvStickerGroup.getCount(); a++) {
                lvStickerGroup.setSelection(a);
            }
            for (int a = lvStickerGroup.getCount() - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                lvStickerGroup.setSelection(a);
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to programmatically scroll to bottom and back to top, same no luck, except programmatically scroll to the item position will not show in the first page when enter the fragment initially.

Besides, I tried to `invalidate()`, `invalidateView()` `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter, same problem occurs, is it possibly a `ListView` bug?

Comment: What is strange in your video? Please be specific.

Comment: First time enter into the fragment that display ListView will not update the progress bar after trigger the button, only scroll down and back to same item only the progress bar will be showing the progress. The progress bar is just testing using some simple increment with sleep for 16ms, it update from ayncTask back to UI...

Comment: Visit [mcve] and edit your question proportionally.

Comment: Sorry, I know my question too broad, I already tried my best, cannot log any exception... I tried few days to implement smooth progress bar in ListView, at the end I found the code in github, but really don't know why cannot implement in fragment, in activity work as expected...  :/

Comment: It's a lot of code and no explanation of what you're trying or the problem you're facing exactly. Please add some text explaining what is that you expect and what is happening when you run your code. You might like to show some screenshots to help us explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code above, fully functional. I found the clue in Google ListView IO conference

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
```

ListView cannot wrap content, else will have bugs showing up. That why I experience such issue.